# Python Online Form Submision

Tags: python, forms, authentication

I am using Python 2.7.1 to access an online website. I need to load a URL, then submit a POST request to that URL that causes the website to redirect to a new URL. I would then like to POST some data to the new URL. This would be easy to do, except that the website in question does not allow the user to use browser navigation. (As in, you cannot just type in the URL of the new page or press the back button, you must arrive there by clicking the "Next" button on the website). Therefore, when I try this:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

url = "http://www.example.com/"

jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
form_data_login = "POSTDATA"
form_data_try = "POSTDATA2"
resp = opener.open(url, form_data_login)
resp2 = opener.open(resp.geturl(), form_data_try)

print resp2.read()
```

I get a "Do not use the back button on your browser" message from the website in resp2. Is there any way to POST data to the website resp gives me? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'll look into Mechanize, so thanks for that pointer. For now, though, is there a way to do it with just Python?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)? I believe it has the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting to that page by posting something via that Next button. You'll have to take a look at the POST parameters sent when pressing that button and add all of these post parameters to your call.

The website *could* though be set up in such a way that it only accepts a particular POST parameter that ensures that you'll have to go through the website itself (e.g. by hashing a timestamp in a certain way or something like that) but it's not very likely.

Comment: I used TamperData, a Firefox extension, to get the POST parameters, though.

Comment: If you're sending the same POST parameters and it's being rejected, the application probably has some kind of mechanism that prevents you from easily just posting to that page. It will be difficult to check it out without having the actual website or at least the forms.

Comment: you should also check the source of the page. If it has CSRF (cross site request forgery) happening there might be hidden fields in the form with token information in them.